# Get non unique values from two arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays,

```
var existingArray = [10,20,30,40];
var newArray =[10,20,30,40,50,60,70];
```

I want to extract non unique elements by using filter from above two arrays and output should be

```
var updatedArray =[50,60,70];
```

I am using javascript es6

Comment: If `newArray` is `[10,20,30,40,50, 50,60,70]` (has two 50s), then should `50` still be included in the output array? Or are you just after getting the difference between your two arrays?

Comment: no. neither existingArray  nor newArray  would have duplicate elements.all elements would be unique ids

Comment: Also, if `existingArray` array is `[10,20,30,40,80]` should `80` be included in the output?

Comment: Does this help?
updatedArray = newArray.filter( (element) => {
 return !existingArray.includes(element);
} );